# What replace silence (capture) kernel method in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the silence method on my spec (http://apidock.com/rails/Kernel/capture).

For example, I want to avoid display on this block :

```
silence(:stdout) do
  ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.purge_current
  ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.load_schema_current
end
```

It work well but it's mark as deprecated since Rails 4.
As it will be remove on next release, I search a replacement but didn't find.

<del>Does something thread-safe exist?</del>
Does a replacement exist?

Comment: Define "thread safe"? In what terms? The reason it's being removed is probably because of issues like this.

Comment: Yes, it's remove before it's not thread safe (it's mark on comment next to the deprecation warning). My question is more : Is there a replacement for this method than 'Is there a real thread safe replacement'? I update the question, sorry. :)

Comment: Probably not. Manipulating globals is almost always a sure-fire way to break thread safety, and hammering on `$stdout` is exactly that.

Comment: Yes, so what people who knew it was not thread safe but nonetheless relied on it in unthreaded contexts such as tests will have to do is simply copypasta it into their own code, thus resulting in thousands of duplicated implementations and a great many wasted hours. Simply yanking functionality with no replacement is every kind of stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing replaced it. Noting that this is not thread-safe, here's what I now have in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
# Silence +STDOUT+ temporarily.
#
# &block:: Block of code to call while +STDOUT+ is disabled.
#
def spec_helper_silence_stdout( &block )
  spec_helper_silence_stream( $stdout, &block )
end

# Back-end to #spec_helper_silence_stdout; silences arbitrary streams.
#
# +stream+:: The output stream to silence, e.g. <tt>$stdout</tt>
# &block::   Block of code to call while output stream is disabled.
#
def spec_helper_silence_stream( stream, &block )
  begin
    old_stream = stream.dup
    stream.reopen( File::NULL )
    stream.sync = true

    yield

  ensure
    stream.reopen( old_stream )
    old_stream.close

  end
end
```

It is inelegant but effective.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Ruby method that silences, or mutes, any output that would typically be printed to standard output (often your terminal or console) while the provided block of code is being executed.

Here's a breakdown of how it works:

It first clones the current standard output ($stdout) to a variable called original_stdout. This is done to preserve the original output stream so it can be restored later.

$stdout.reopen(File.new('/dev/null', 'w')): This line is redirecting the $stdout to /dev/null. In Unix-like operating systems, /dev/null is a special file that discards all data written to it (and returns an end-of-file EOF when read). In simpler terms, it's like a "black hole" that will swallow whatever is sent to it. The 'w' argument means that the file is opened for writing.

block.call executes the block of code that was passed to the silence_stdout method. Any output this code would typically print to the terminal is instead sent to /dev/null, effectively silencing it.

The ensure block is there to make sure that the original $stdout is restored, even if an error occurs during the execution of the block of code. This is important because you wouldn't want one error to prevent you from seeing the output of all your subsequent code.

This method is particularly useful when you have a section of your code that prints to the console, but you do not want to see these print statements, perhaps because they're cluttering up your output or because they contain sensitive information. You simply wrap that section of code in this silence_stdout method, and it will prevent anything from being printed to the console while that code is running.

```
def silence_stdout(&block)
  original_stdout = $stdout.clone
  $stdout.reopen(File.new('/dev/null', 'w'))
  begin
    block.call
  ensure
    $stdout.reopen(original_stdout)
  end
end
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?